# What is this part: 2n2 630?

Tags: components, device, identification

I'm trying to identify a part I removed from a compact fluorescent lamp manufactured around 9 years ago (date on the PCB is 17.12.01).

It is a gray hexahedron and it's 7 mm wide, 2 mm long and about 4.5 mm high. Contacts are on the 2 mm sides.

The inscription on it says in the first line 2n2 and in the second line 630.

Judging by the inscription, device seems to be manufactured in a long sheet on which numbers were printed and then cut into 5 mm high segments.

At first I thought it could be some sort of capacitor (PCB has capacitor mark on its location), but after some testing, I was unable to charge it and then measure its voltage (on the other hand, it could be that it has very low capacitance so could discharge itself in the time it takes me to switch my multimeter form ohmmeter mode to voltmeter mode). Also, part which is obviously resistor was next to the unknown device and it too had capacitor mark on PCB.

I did some research on the Internet, but as far as I can tell, 2n2630 is a transistor and this definitely does not look like a transistor, so I'm looking here for ideas on what it could be.

**EDIT**
I finally managed to get a nice picture of the part on 1 mm grid. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of it?

Comment: What sort of hexahedron is it? a cuboid? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hexahedron.html

Comment: @Joby Taffey♦ Well, I don't have a camera which can catch the inscription on the part. I'll try to post an image anyway. It's a cuboid hexahedron.

Comment: @Joby Taffey♦ @Turbo J I've managed to add an image of the part.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say its a Capacitor with 2,2nF capacity and voltage up to 630 V. A usual multimeter has 10µA (or more) current flow, which will discharge this low capacity very very quickly - no chance for reading a voltage here.

Comment: I've been looking for some capacitors in that range, and polyester film capacitor from [Wikipedia ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Condensators.JPG) looks just like the thing I've got. Another [link](http://www.piclist.com/images/www/hobby_elec/e_capa.htm) under Metallized Polyester Film Capacitors.

Comment: @turbo J -You are correct  2.2 nanofarad @ 630V Ceramic capacitor. Probably a bypass capacitor shunting RF emissions to ground.

Answer (score 4):

Like Turbo says it's a 2.2 nF, 630V capacitor. It's an MK* type, where the * designates the dielectricum, this could be an MKM, meaning metal layer (first M), plastic (the K) with polycarbonate dielectricum (the second M).
Note that the sides are not insulated.

Answer (score 0):

OMG ! That's a Siemens MKT range capacitor,

2.2nF or 2200pF whichever you prefer, 630V.

Polyester film. Used to see lots of them decades ago, Once very popular, especially in European products. The capacitance value is proportional to the length of the body, which is 'cut' to length to suit the value.

Available in 5mm and 7.5mm pitch.